# PHP POST stalls out on mobile safari

Tags: php, html, mobile, safari

When I click a button to submit a form it stalls about 70% of the time. Not every time, but the majority of the time. It stalls for about 30 seconds then lands on a blank white page.

This bug seems to only be apparent in mobile safari (iOS 7 is what I am using). It works in mobile chrome and all 5 major computer browsers.

I cut EVERYTHING not needed out and am left with this:

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['goBack'])){
    header('Location: survey.php');
    exit();
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="input.php" method="post">
    A Test:
    <input type="text" id="inputBar" value="test" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="goBack" value="Back" />
</form>
```

The form posts to itself which redirects elsewhere.

Comment: did you check if the timed-out post is actually reaching your server? e.g. does your phone's IP show up in the server's `netstat` output?

Comment: I don't think it is hitting the server. How can I verify an individual post?

Comment: `tcp        0      0 cpe:8000                192.xxx.xxx.xxx:54944   ESTABLISHED`

there is my entry from my IP when I make the request